# Docker Build Command Results in File Not Found Error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I try to run:

```
docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=target/*.jar -t myapp -f .\Dockerfile .
```

And I get the error:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2423436051/.Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

I went online and the blog posts suggested to name the docker file Dockerfile, which I believe that I have done.

What is wrong with this command?

I ran the command and I got that error.

UPDATE:
I updated the command to: `docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=target/*.jar -t myapp .` but I still get the error. Below are the files/folders in my current directory:

```
/var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3815898823/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

README.adoc             mvnw                    node_modules            package.json            src                     webpack.config.js
images                  mvnw.cmd                package-lock.json       pom.xml                 target
```

Comment: `Dockerfile` is the default name; you don't need the `-f` option at the end.  If you're not on a Windows system, the backslash might be confusing the builder.

Comment: `Dockerfile` not `.Dockerfile`. There is no `.`

Comment: Thanks for the info! However, running docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=target/*.jar -t myapp -f . I get this error:

Comment: ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify `Dockerfile`, instead do:

```
cd /where/is/Dockerfile
docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=target/*.jar -t myapp .
```

Only use `-f` with different names of files than `Dockerfile`.

Comment: So I have tried that command, and I get: ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.

Comment: I don't wrote `docker buildx build`

Comment: Fixed forgot `-f`: removed

Comment: I copied just what you had in your post,

Comment: Now I get this error, which is why I specified the docker filename:

Comment: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3815898823/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: Do you have `Dockerfile` in the current directory?

Comment: Apologies, I don't follow. I'm in the directory of my Sprint Boot project, `/Users/ben/IdeaProjects/ReactAndSpringWorking`, and this is what is in that directory:

``README.adoc             mvnw                    node_modules            package.json            src                     webpack.config.js
images                  mvnw.cmd                package-lock.json       pom.xml                 target``

Comment: Read Docker's documentation instead of trying random commands. The first step is to create a `Dockerfile`.